# How to make my table look like this

Tags: html, css

Alright, I know this looks wierd, but how can I make my HTML table look like this?

What I want is two in length at the beginning, then three.

```
 _  _
| ||_|
|-||_|
|_||_|
```

I've tried several things already, but it just looks funky every time jsfiddle.net/uyvx0mL9

Comment: You should show us your best attempt, so that we can guide you to a solution.

Comment: You can do table-in-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

Here is an even better version than table-in-table

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  width: 100px;
}

th, td {  
  padding:10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3"></th>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<strike>A table-in-table version</strike>

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td rowspan="2">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard of the CSS property display:table?

Here is a great tutorial on it to see the possibilities:
http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

For your particular problem you could treat the left and right as if they were two separate 1 column tables.

Another approach would be to use one table but then instead of table cells use an unordered list with a border inside.

Hopefully this helps you go in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Row 1</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer yet, but there was a downvote. FYI, I corrected that.

Comment: I can see why it was downvoted, seeing as this is NOT the solution the OP was asking for, nor similar.

Comment: @apollo And now there is an even better, that layout exactly how OP asked :) ... maybe an up vote for that one too?